# How to use recursion to find longest valid DNA sequences?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have a project that I just cannot understand. It requires using recursion to find the longest valid DNA sequence when given two strands. I am given a file called dna.txt. The first line of the file contains a number that is how many pairs of DNA strands there will be. Then the rest of the lines are strings of DNA. My job is to look at each pair of strands individually and find the longest valid DNA sequence and write it into a new file called dnaresults.txt. If this was to be done through iteration I'm fairly confident I could handle it. But the project requires that I use recursion to a)find valid DNA sequences and b)find the longest DNA pairs. I understand recursion on a very basic level (Fibonacci, rolling sum, etc.) but I just cannot wrap my head around how to apply it in this situation.

For example, the input file will look like follows:

```
3
GAAGCTCG
CCTCGGGA
AAATTT
GGGCCC
CTCTAGGAC
GAGTACCTG
```

and I am required to output this to a new file:

```
DNA sequence pair 0:
AGC
TCG

DNA sequence pair 1:
No matches found

DNA sequence pair 2:
GGAC
CCTG
```

This is what I have tried so far. I can use the number to determine how many times to execute my loop. I can get the pair of strands separated and in their own variable. But once the time has come to evaluate and compare them I'm stumped because I don't understand how to use recursion in this case.

```
def main():
    dnaFile = open('dna.txt').readlines()
    numOfPairs = int(dnaFile[0])

    for i in range(0, numOfPairs*2, 2):
        firstStrand = str(dnaFile[i+1])
        secondStrand = str(dnaFile[i+2])
        firstStrand.upper()
        secondStrand.upper()
```

So that's where I'm at right now. If anyone could point me in the right direction with the recursion that would be amazing. I'm really just so clueless as to how I'm supposed to use recursion to compare the DNA strands while also storing and returning only the longest one. Thanks in advance!

Edit: My apologies. A DNA sequence is valid when an A on one strand is paired with a T on another (and vice versa) and a G on one strand is paired with a C on another (and vice versa).

```
ACTGTC
TGACAG
```

That is a valid sequence because every pair is A-T or G-C.

```
ACTGTC
GCACTA
```

That is not a completely valid sequence because not every pair is A-T or G-C. Only the 3rd and 4th pairs are valid (TG and AC).

Comment: I could look it up but to make our lives easier can you add what makes the DNA valid.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Corresponding basepairs: A goes with T, and G goes with C.

Comment: Can we assume that you only need to write a recursive function that, given two strands of DNA, returns the longest matching subsequences? That's bad enough, but requiring recursion to iterate over the file would just be asinine.

Comment: @chepner Yes I just need one function that takes two strands and compares them and returns the longest valid subsequence. And I can just call it multiple times, once for each pair. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: This question isn't a good one for recursion it can be done using a linear solution. This type of problem would just take up a large amount of stack.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Trust me, I'd rather do it any other way as well. But the project requires recursion otherwise it's a 0 so my back is to the wall.

Comment: Do you have to consider shifts? Given `ACTGC` and `GACGT`, would the answer be no match or `CTGC`/`GACG`?

Comment: @chepner No shifts are not considered thank you for asking. The paired strings will always be the same length as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion for this type of problem uses a stupid amount of stack and is significantly slower than using built in data structures that take linear time and constant space. I understand recursion is needed because that is your problem but I still feel like I should say that.

Here is a recursive solution:

**First a function to check for valid pairs:**

```
def valid_pair(c1, c2):
    pairs = {
      'G': 'C',
      'C': 'G',
      'A': 'T',
      'T': 'A'
    }
    return pairs[c1] == c2
```

**Now the recursion method:**

```
def compare_strands(s1, s2, count=0, result=["", ""]):
    if not s1 or not s2: # base case
        return count, result
    # If it is not a valid pair
    if not valid_pair(s1[0], s2[0]):
        old_max, old_str = count, result
        new_max, new_str = compare_strands(s1[1:], s2[1:], 0, ["", ""])
        if new_max < old_max:
            new_max = old_max
            new_str = old_str
    else:
        temp_result = []
        temp_result.append(result[0] + s1[0])
        temp_result.append(result[1] + s2[0])
        # result[1] += s2[0]
        count = count + 1
        new_max, new_str = compare_strands(s1[1:], s2[1:], count, temp_result)
    return new_max, new_str
```

**Testing:**

```
with open('dna.txt', 'r') as f:
    size = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(size):
        strand1 = f.readline().strip('\n')
        strand2 = f.readline().strip('\n')
        print(compare_strands(strand1, strand2))
```

**Output:**

```
(3, ['AGC', 'TCG'])
(0, ['', ''])
(4, ['GGAC', 'CCTG'])
```

**Edit:** To write to file.

```
with open('dna.txt', 'r') as f:
    size = int(f.readline())
    for i in range(size):
        strand1 = f.readline().strip('\n')
        strand2 = f.readline().strip('\n')
        result = compare_strands(strand1, strand2)
        with open('result.txt', 'a') as result_file:
            result_file.write('DNA sequece pair {}:\n'.format(i))
            if result[0]:
                result_file.write('{}\n{}\n\n'.format(result[1][0], result[1][1]))
            else:
                result_file.write('No matches found\n\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is very helpful! I'm still not sure what's going on here but I'll see if I can break it down

Comment: After you break it down, if it answers your question don't forget to mark it as an answer! It helps a lot :)

Comment: Okay I don't really understand the recursion but that's okay lol. Would you mind explaining to me how I can get the results from the compare_strands function into the format I need? I need to somehow write to a new file within the for loop that's in the read code block. I'll mark it as answered anyway thank you for all the help!

Comment: See my edit. I added the output. Though be careful copying this as is because a plagiarism check will probably catch it.

Comment: Hmm well that just about works except that the results are just added to the results file when I need to completely overwrite it. I assume that's what the "a" is doing? I tried changing it to "w" but then it only puts the results for the last pair of strands

Comment: Move the `with` statement out of the other `with` then change some stuff around and use `w` instead of `a`. It should work

Comment: The problem with that is that now that the writing statement is outside of the for loop the strand1/strand2 are stored with the final result of the loop.

Comment: Nevermind I got it!! I just removed the with statements and opened them as ```f = open('dna.txt', 'r')``` and the same with the file to write and then manually closed them afterwards. Thank you for everything!